# Weekly water tables that interact with each other

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am learning C#, ASP.NET and MVC. I am making an application and I am just wondering about the best way to go about it. It is an application that takes in water readings input by a user and some values are gotten automatically from the input each day, with some of the readings only being taken once a week. My first problem is what is the best way to make the table(s). There's values for every day and I'd like them split up into weeks too. Should I have one big table or many, maybe weekly? I feel weekly would be inefficient though.

Each week has to interact also, with values from the next week needed to calculate values for the current one. For example, say there's a row in the table called "Water Reading" and the columns are "Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday" and a total usage column at the end. So in week 1, that readings are taken each day, and when it get's to the Monday in week 2, the reading on Monday in week 1 is subtracted from the Monday in week 2 to get the total usage, and that is put in the total usage column in week 1.

A similar thing is done for each day, eg, Monday's reading is subtracted from Tuesday's reading to get Monday's usage.
I'm just looking for pointers and ideas on how to organise the tables and ways to have interactions mentioned above.

Comment: You won't necessarily need the additional columns as you can always get the calculations from the original data.  I would recommend you make a table which holds "weeks" and thus has 9 columns, auto-index, a "week beginning date" column and a column for each day of the week.  Alternatively you can make a table which just holds "day" data with date and reading.  Then you can do queries for example all days within month x or in year y etc etc.

Comment: Off-topic for Stack Overflow. Perhaps on-topic at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, map out exactly what you want to do, and how to design the application fro ma high level. Then go and design a database to allow this. It's an exercise in logic.

TBH, I wouldn't bother splitting it out into different tables as you'd have to deal with creating new tables every week. There are many ways you could handle it. You could have a "weeks" table which would contain the relationship which would define the data related to the week and any data which is shared across the readings table. The water table then contains the individual readings, and are associated with a week record.

But tbh this is probably the wrong place to ask. Find a book on application design. Don't have a good reference to hand though.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single table with a DateTime column, you can later interact with weeks, months or whatever manipulating the date using [the vast array of properties and methods from .net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)